# FileWriter issue - unreported IOEXception which must be caught

Tags: java, exception, java-io, filewriter

I've encountered an issue in Java trying to write to a file using FileWriter. Simply declaring `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("filelocation");` yields that there is an unreported IOException which must be caught.

To rectify this, naturally I put my FileWriter within a try-catch block, but that causes an issue with scope. To fix this, I tried declaring the FileWriter before the try catch block and assigning the location within the try catch. After the try catch block when I would like to use the FileWriter, it tells me it may not have been initialized. I'm not certain how else to handle this, and never encountered this issue in Java 1.7 or likewise.

This is an example of my final situation in case I was unclear;

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
FileWriter writer;
try {
    System.out.println("Enter the file directory you would like to store in");
    String fileLocation = userInput.nextLine();
    writer = new FileWriter(fileLocation);
} catch(java.io.IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error message");
}
writer.write("Stuff"); //writer may not have been initialized
```

Comment: This is intended behavior. You need to perform `writer.write` in the try block under the constructor call.

Comment: The issue with that is in my actual code there is about another 90 lines of code before I ever use the writer. I would think it is poor practice to just put it all in the try block. Am I wrong in that regard?

As an aside, this seems like strange intended behavior. If there was an error initializing the FileWriter within the try catch, it would exit the method when the error is thrown and therefor never call writer.write. I'm becoming split in my opinion on 1.8 altogether!

Comment: Jason: It is semantically correct for it to be in the try block. However, something that is more appropriate would be a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look at that. I should be able to get it sorted with what you've told me, so thank you greatly!

Comment: I would suggest you drop that catch block and declare that your method (`main`?) throws the exception.

Comment: The Java `FileWriter` has thrown `IOExceptions` since 1997. It is not 'an issue with Java 1.8'.

Answer (score 0):

The good way :

```
System.console().printf("Enter the file directory you would like to store in");
String location = System.console().readLine();
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter (location)) {
  writer.write("Stuff");
} catch (IOException e) {
  new RuntimeException("Error message", e).printStackTrace();
}
```

Explanations:

1. `System.console().printf()` enable to print message on [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29). `System.out` may be prefered is having a "console" is not strictly required.
2. Uses `System.console()` for console management. Much easier and clearer. Don't forget to allocate a console (ie don't use `javaw` executable).
3. Opens stream using [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)
4. `printStackTrace()` print on [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) which ease finding error location in code.
5. I have built a new Exception to attach your error message with the stack trace adds the "catch" location in the stack.

Advices:

1. Uses byte-stream for file access (ie [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileOutputStream.html)). It enables to enforce charset (ie [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html)) and buffering (ie [BufferedOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) or [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/BufferedWriter.html)).
2. Using byte-stream makes also possible to switch to [NIO Channel API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/nio/channels/package-summary.html).
3. Uses [StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) to access default (and largely commonly used) charset (Charsets that all JVM implementations must support)
4. Read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
5. call to `printStackTrace()` isn't really nice and you should quickly introduce a logging system to print messages.
6. In case of a [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface), have good attention when using logging system to not confuse user about system interactions (ie prompt for user input) and feedbacks (ie progress message)

Comment: Since OP obviously doesn't care about encoding, using `FileWriter` is a better choice. Don't complicate the code now for something you may never need. You can always refactor later if the need changes. --- Catching the exception and printing the stack trace, then letting the code continue, is a recipe for disaster. Unless you've *handled* the exception, you very rarely want the following code to execute.

Comment: Why do you believe using `System.console()` is better than `System.out` for printing a message? Especially when you don't print the stack trace that way?

Comment: Why create a new `RuntimeException` (creating an all new additional but useless stacktrace), just to print the stacktrace of the thrown `IOException`?

Comment: You should realize that `System.console()` could return `null` depending on the IDE used. Stick to using `System.out` to print to the console and avoid the risk of using exception-prone code.

Comment: @Andreas I have seen too many lack of encoding/charset management to  don't educate dummies (Not excuses). Refer to [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @Andreas (about `System.console()`) I also prefer using System.out but I have prefered focus on consistency (which may be less error confusing for dummies). In the same idea, I don't use it to printStackTrace for two abvious reason : simplicity and lack of stderr support in [Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/Console.html) class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This construction is a pure cheap replacement for logging system. Uses log is largely a better approach but require most than a small SO answer. If you have a good link about logging management introduction, feel free to edit my post to add it ;)

Comment: @Andreas (about error management). Error management is a long topic in robustness area. And it definitively can't be discussed on a code snippet without any business and architectural background. I just keep the same logic. If you have suggestions about it, I'm be very pleased to hear (or read edit suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

You say "naturally" you put it within a try-catch block. There's nothing natural about that, since there are two ways to handle it, and the other way is more common:

- Handle the exception in a try-catch block.
- Don't handle the exception, but declare that your method throws the exception, and allow it to cascade up the call stack.

Your code looks like it's in a `main` method, so you could add `throws IOException`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

---

In your particular case, however, you're getting the file location from a user prompt, so rather than letting the program die with an error, the appropriate thing would be to tell the user about the error and prompt for a new name.

Also, remember to close your resources.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    FileWriter writer;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the file name you would like to store in");
        String fileLocation = userInput.nextLine();
        if (fileLocation.trim().isEmpty())
            return; // Exit program when user pressed enter with a name
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(fileLocation);
        } catch(java.io.IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot write to file: " + e);
            writer = null;
        }
    } while (writer == null);
    try {
        writer.write("Stuff"); //writer may not have been initialized
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

The `write` and the `close` can still technically throw an error (e.g. disk full), which we allow to cascade and kill the program.